# Using desolve package in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new at R and I'm  trying to solve ODEs system(dx_1,dx_2,dx_3) . I have no problem with solving ODEs, but I want to calculate the `C=x_1+x_2` in each values of `x_1` and `x_2` how can i write that inside my code.